# h:commandLink not invoked if Java Script is placed inside h:panelGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-1.2

Below is the code,

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.showDialogBox}"> //Boolean value from bean decides
//if Jquery Dialog box has to be shown or not for this User.

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */


   var $h=jQuery.noConflict();          
   function myFunction() 
   {

        $h(document).ready(function() {

            $h("#someDivID").dialog({

                // Dialog box attributes go here
        });
   }

   myFunction();  // Call myFunction to render Jquery Dialog box

/* ]]> */
</script>


<div id="someDivID"> //Below JSF component gets displayed inside Jquery Dialog box
    <h:commandLink value="Click Here" action="#{myBean.someMethod}"></h:commandLink>
</div>

</h:panelGroup>
```

**Problem :** 
If I remove `h:panelGroup`, my `h:commandLink` works fine(calls bean method). But, I can't remove `h:panelGroup` as this dialog box has to be shown only to few Users based on pre defined conditions.
I want to make use of `rendered` attribute of `h:panelGroup`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you're running JSF 1.2 and not 1.1 or 1.0? The `<f:verbatim>` is totally unnecessary in this construct since JSF 1.2.

Comment: If your `<h:panelGroup>` isn't rendered, then **none** of its contents will, this means, no HTML/CSS/JS inside it will be place on generated HTML. Your best best would be moving all the JS/CSS code outside it.

Comment: @BalusC Am using JSF 1.2. I didn't get that `<f:varbatim>` is unnecessary. I have removed that now. And I have edited my question and answer where I have removed `<f:verbatim>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by placing `h:panelGroup` just after `</script>`

Below is the code,

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.showDialogBox}"> //Boolean value from bean decides
//if Jquery Dialog box has to be shown or not for this User.


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */


   var $h=jQuery.noConflict();          
   function myFunction() 
   {

        $h(document).ready(function() {

            $h("#someDivID").dialog({

                // Dialog box attributes go here
        });
   }

   myFunction();  // Call myFunction to render Jquery Dialog box

/* ]]> */
</script>

</h:panelGroup> // This is what was required

<div id="someDivID"> //Below JSF component gets displayed inside Jquery Dialog box
    <h:commandLink value="Click Here" action="#{myBean.someMethod}"></h:commandLink>
</div>
```

But, would appreciate if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a div within a span issue.  Try adding layout="block" in your h:panelGroup  so that it renders as a div.